# "Dir(path) <> vbNullString" gives false negatives if path is an empty folder or contains only subfolders

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

(I made a similar question recently. I've deleted it because I realised I was wrong about what's causing the error.)

I have a spreadsheet containing cells with file paths in them. I wanted to automate checking to see if the file paths really exist. It appears to be working, **except** for paths of folders that contain no files directly within them. I.e. empty folders, or folders that contain only subfolders.

Is there any way around this (other than putting a tiny file in each of the affected folders)?

I'm using this function:

```
Function FileExist(path As String) As Boolean
    If Dir(path) <> vbNullString Then FileExist = True
End Function
```

And within the spreadsheet I use
`=FileExist(A1)`
to return TRUE or FALSE, where A1 is a cell reference that holds a file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function):

> Dir returns the first file name that matches pathname.

So if the directory in question doesn't contain any files, nothing is returned. So your FileExist function will return False.

You mention:

> empty folders, or folders that contain only subfolders

To get your function to also return True for those, we can add the `vbDirectory` optional argument.

```
If Dir(path, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then FileExist = True
```

From the above documentation:

> The *attributes* argument settings are:
>
> ...
>
> **vbDirectory** … Specifies directories or folders in addition to files with no attributes.

So if you change your function to look like this, it should do what you are expecting.

```
Function FileExist(path As String) As Boolean
    If Dir(path, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then FileExist = True
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from a friend: use object.FolderExists to check for folders. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/folderexists-method

```
Function FolderExist(path As String) As Boolean
    Dim MyFSO As FileSystemObject
    Set MyFSO = New FileSystemObject
    If MyFSO.FolderExists(path) Then FolderExist = True
End Function
```

So now I use either FolderExist(A1) or FileExist(A1), depending on what I'm looking at. It's probably less elegant than Doug Deden's solution, but it does what I wanted it to.

Comment: Oh, if anyone else wanted to try using this object, you need to enable Microsoft Scripting Runtime (go to Tools, then References, then ensure 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' is ticked).